# Passing values to KSH scripts from Python

Tags: python, shell, input, ksh

I'm using Python to run a .ksh script, using subprocess.call().

This script requires the user to enter text at certain points - whatever the equivalent of Python's input() is in KSH I guess.

The problem I'm having is that I have to run the script ~200 times, and I don't want to have to enter this information each time. Is there anyway that I can set it up so that these requests for user input are automatically given some value each time without the user even needing to do anything?

I'm pretty new to using Python at the shell in this way, so apologies if this question doesn't make sense. Happy to take any feedback. I haven't found this question asked previously - mostly people ask about passing arguments to the script - but I may have missed something as I was having trouble finding the key search terms.

The Python version is 2.7, and it's a UNIX environment.

Comment: You need to feed the data to the script on `stdin`. The subprocess module lets you do that.

Comment: Can you modify the script? It's certainly _possible_ to write to its stdin, but would be better practice to change its calling convention to allow arguments to be passed in through a means other than stdin -- environment variables, command-line arguments, etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can save your parameters in Python and give them on the commandline each time you call the script.
2. Your script can store them in a file (or database, service, ..) and read them when started again.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent to Python's `input()` in any POSIX-compliant shell, including ksh, is `read`.

---

Thus, on the Python side:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['yourscript'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate(arg1 + '\n' + arg2 + '\n')
```

...and on the shell side:

```
IFS= read -r arg1
IFS= read -r arg2
```

Clearing `IFS` and passing `-r` make the interpretation more closely literal, so strings containing, say, the two characters `\n` on the Python side don't get interpreted as containing only a single newline character, and avoiding automatic stripping of trailing whitespace on the shell end of the transaction.

---

If your string can contain newlines and such, then you'll want to emit it from your Python program with a trailing NUL character:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['yourscript'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate(arg1 + '\0' + arg2 + '\0')
```

...and read it as so from the shell end:

```
IFS= read -r -d '' arg1
IFS= read -r -d '' arg2
```

This is more powerful than the `input()` equivalent you asked for, since it can handle arbitrary C strings. (Python's native strings are Pascal-style, and so can contain literal NULs; neither ksh nor any other existing POSIX-style shell can handle all values of these literally without using very unpleasant tricks).

---

That said, it would typically be better practice to pass arguments on the command line or through the environment, rather than reading from stdin as you propose. Thus:

```
subprocess.Popen(['yourscript', arg1, arg2], shell=False)
```

...where `arg1` and `arg2` are the variables with the content you wish to pass, which then can be referred to as `$1` and `$2` in the script. Alternately, variables can be passed through the environment:

```
subprocess.Popen(['yourscript'], shell=False, env={
  'arg1': arg1,
  'arg2': arg2,
})
```

...in which case the ksh script can refer directly to `"$arg1"` and `"$arg2"` for the values.

---

Consider finding the places where your script currently runs:

```
read arg1
```

and replacing it with

```
[[ $arg1 ]] || read arg1
```

...which will read a value from `arg1` from stdin only if no other value was already provided (as through the environment). This makes your script still interactively usable prompting the user through the command line as it always did, but provides an alternative behavior of reading content directly from the environment as well.